# Link Only Answers

Tags: discussion

When flagging link only answers (either from review or direct) could you actually comment on the answer to explain to the OP why link only answers are bad?

We seem to get a heap of them in the admin flags and inevitably that's all I do each time anyway as the idea is to give people a chance to rectify things. It's not a big thing but it's a bit of a pain when I have to sit and go through multiple cases of this a day and I'm sure Samuel sees more than a few too!

Comment: Are you talking about when someone *flags* them or when they go through the review queue which *does* explain why they're bad? Here's a snippet I use: "Welcome to SF.SE (username). Its preferred you provide some details from the link giving credit to the author, should the link ever disappear. If you will, please update your answer with more information."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to explain from my side of things (I'm sure I'm one of the worst offenders):

If you look at the way `Badges` are laid out, they actually strongly encourage this behavior.

- The `Marshall` badge rewards 500 accepted flags
- `Low Quality Post` and other reviewer badges are awarded at 1000 review items

So if I just leave a comment, no one gets any badge progress. If I flag it as link only and someone agrees, we *both* make badge progress. It seems to be the flow the system is designed to incentivize. Also, when accepted as `Link Only Answer` in the `Low Quality Post` queue, it auto-comments with similar material.

One counter-argument, I suppose, is that we may not feel the question should be *deleted* just because it *may break later*. Sometimes in the review queue, we see a link only answer where *the accepted answer* is, in fact, only a link. Often this answer is highly voted. It would be more consistent to respond to both `Answers` with a comment, or both with a flag. As I understand it, deleting any post causes you to lose the reputation gained from it, and that seems harsh for something that was deemed useful.

If we are to post a comment, perhaps [this comment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120397/i-am-not-able-to-create-vf-page/120399?cid=169879#120399) can serve as a template:

> Welcome to SFSE [user]! Can you post some of the relevant content from that link? Links tend to break over time making answers without details a bit useless in the long term :)

For a less green user, I might comment:

> Can you post some relevant content from that link? Links tend to break over time, making answers without details less useful in the long term.

Comment: You make progress towards your review queue badges for every post you review, regardless of whether you vote to delete a post or accept it as "It's Okay, No Action Needed, etc". This allows you to make comments without voting a post for deletion. I suggest you ask yourself whether you're here to earn badges or make the forum a better place for all. (no offense intended)

Comment: @crmprogdev I think getting a link only answer deleted *is* improving our quality a lot of the time. We can't just delete them ourselves.

Comment: It does help, but I'd rather see those answers expanded. If people reviewing can add those comments themselves as well as flagging it would make my day a lot less repetitive :)

Comment: @LaceySnr I always try to make a judgment call. If I think there is a good chance of improvement, I comment and don't bother with the flag. But if expansion seems unlikely to happen or to help, I go for deletion.

Comment: I think the approach I took here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140289/relationship-fields-not-accessible-on-reports-for-partner-community-user/140296#comment202310_140296 of just commenting and giving the poster time to improve the answer is best for the community.